# regular expression that matches unless a character is present?

Tags: python, regex

How can I match 'x' with any amount of whitespace on the right side, Unless the 'x' is followed by another 'x'?

So far I have:

```
find_nonSpace_rightSideOf_x = re.compile(r'x[\s]*')
```

But obviously, this will still catch even if the text is 'xx'. How can I make this catch 'xaldkfjda', 'x     ', 'x adkf', etc., but not the first x in: 'xxaldkfjdlk', 'xx    ', etc.?

EDIT: The end of the last sentence should read "...but not the first TWO x's in: 'xxaldkfjdlk', 'xx    ', etc.?" In short, I want to catch one 'x', but never two x's - 'xx' - side by side. Does that help? Thanks for your inputs so far!

Comment: For what reason do you escape the x?

Comment: Can you put a sample output and your expected match?

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative look ahead assertion:

```
re.compile(r'x(?!x)')
```

Will *catch* the second `x` in `'xxaldkfjdlk'`

> but not the first x

To *catch* the spaces, add: `\s*`

```
re.compile(r'x(?!x)\s*')
```

Some trials:

```
>>> m = re.compile(r'x(?!x)\s*')
>>> m.search('xx  ')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 4), match='x  '>
>>> m.search('xxaldkfjdlk')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 2), match='x'>
>>> m.search('xxxx')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(3, 4), match='x'>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another simple solution would be this:

```
x[^x][\s]*
```

I.e. 'x' followed by "not-x", followed by spaces.

BTW, a very useful tool is the python regex tester: http://pythex.org/

Comment: this regex matches a `x` not a `x` and multiple spaces

Comment: I think you wanted to write `x[^x]*\s*`

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. due to the OP not being very clear.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to match the last `x` to the end of the line.

To do that you can use this regex:

```
x[^x]*$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/eN2cU6/1)**

[image]